# ¿Por qué me sale el error "argumentos incorrectos, fuera del intervalo permitido"?

Tags: c#, sql

Se dispara el error:

> argumentos incorrectos, fuera del intervalo permitido

en la línea que comenté en el código:

```cs
string b;

OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\SPRmercado.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1L0v3Acce55;");

cn.Open();
if (cboCampo.Text == "Nombre" || cboCampo.Text == "Fecha_nacimiento" || cboCampo.Text == "Sexo" || cboCampo.Text == "Area" || cboCampo.Text == "Cargo" || cboCampo.Text == "Fecha_ingreso" || cboCampo.Text == "Salario_mensual" || cboCampo.Text == "No_contrato") {

    b = "Select * from Empleados where " + cboCampo.Text + "=" + "\"" + txtDato.Text + "\"";

    OleDbCommand cmm = new OleDbCommand(b, cn);

    ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();

    rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset;

    rs.Open(b, cn);        // <---- Línea en la que se dispara el error

    dgvDatos.Rows.Clear();
    dgvDatos.Refresh();

    dgvDatos.Columns.Add("idEmpleado", "idEmpleado");
    dgvDatos.Columns.Add("Nombre", "Nombre");
    dgvDatos.Columns.Add("Fecha_nacimiento", "Fecha_nacimiento");
    dgvDatos.Columns.Add("Sexo", "Sexo");
    dgvDatos.Columns.Add("Area", "Area");
    dgvDatos.Columns.Add("Cargo", "Cargo");
    dgvDatos.Columns.Add("Fecha_ingreso", "Fecha_ingreso");
    dgvDatos.Columns.Add("Salario_mensual", "Salario_mensual");
    dgvDatos.Columns.Add("No_contrato", "No_contrato");


    for (int fila = 0; fila <= rs.RecordCount - 1; fila++) {
        dgvDatos.Rows.Add();
        for (int columna = 0; columna <= 8; columna++) {
            dgvDatos.Rows[fila].Cells[columna].Value = Convert.ToString(rs.Fields[columna].Value);
        }
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
    rs.Close();
}
cn.Close();

}
```

Comment: Intenta `b = "Select * from Empleados where " + cboCampo.Text + "='" + txtDato.Text + "'";`.De todas maneras,debes utilizar SIEMPRE consultas parametrizadas,SIEMPRE, para evitar por un lado este tipo de problemas y por otro SQL Injection

Comment: Sigue igual... :c

Comment: No se controló COMexception                        
Argumentos incorrectos, fuera de intervalo permitido o en conflicto con otros

Comment: Tienes que darnos algun dato mas, por ejemplo en que linea te está lanzando la excepción

Comment: en esta: rs.Open(b, cn);

Comment: Hmm..ahora que miro tu código.Estás usando un oledb mezclado con ADODB????? Creo que debes repasar un poco los conceptos

Comment: [Aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx) tienes un ejemplo de conexión oledb. Revisalo bien y modifica tu código de acuerdo a el.

Comment: @Pikoh quizás sería mejor publicarlo como respuesta, con un fragmento de código que lo ejemplifique.

Comment: Revisé tu código y me surgió una duda, ¿la variable `cmm`  para qué te funciona? Creo qu no la utilizas en algún otro lado.

Answer (score 1):

Dos puntos importantes.

1.- Las consultas que validan campos de texto deben ser entre comillas simples:

```
b = "Select * from Empleados where " + cboCampo.Text + "=" + "'" + txtDato.Text + "'";
```

**Actualización:**

El `RecordSet` deberá recibir los parámetros para la ejecución del query, para eso, necesitamos cambiar estas 3 líneas:

```
ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();
rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset;
rs.Open(b, cn);
```

Por estas:

```
ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();
rs.Open(b, cn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, -1);
```

2.- Evita utilizar consultas armando queries de forma dinámica ya que es suceptible a **`SQL Injection`**, es preferible el acceso a datos a través de `Stored Procedures` o enviando información con parámetros.

En este [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) (principalmente el paso 2 y paso 3) puedes encontrar mayor información para evitar **`SQL Injection`**